# JavaScript MySQL query to function

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a question me need select from database field to  my function `addValue()`
how correctly add values from query to function?
my code

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '192.168.1.5',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'tsou'
});
connection.connect();

var options = null;
connection.query('select pyear from pyear', function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    options = result;

});

function addValue() {
    var select = document.getElementById("tsou_year");

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
connection.end();
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1) redefine your function addValue as:

```
function addValue(err, options, fields)
```

2) call connection.query and pass it your addValue function

```
connection.query('select pyear from pyear', addValue)
```